# Transforming data on a per-instance basis

Tags: data-transformation, dataset, scales

I am currently facing the following situation (in my feature engineering process):

- I am inspecting a step function for a set of instances (step function per instance), i.e., in each iteration "i" there is a functional value correspondingly.
- I am deriving several features from this trajectory, e.g. slope in a certain part or volumes spanned by any lower bound and the respective trajectory line.

Now, comes the problem:

- each instance is generated based on a certain class which leads to certain "niveaus" of functional values, e.g. some might start in i = 0 at y = 100000000, some start at y = 100
- my features now seem to adequately seperate those instances -- but this comes from these high discrepency in y-value niveaus. These niveaus, however, can change so the 100000000 might 100 when generated that way (nevertheless the instances/data is given I do not have to generate instances by myself)

What am I looking for?:

- I want to gain generalizability in my model
- idea so far: transform the y-values in the the trajectories so my feature values will become independent of whatever "niveau" is there. But how do I achieve that based on an instance-base only (so NOT taking all instances and normalize on [0,1] scale or whatever).

Glad you guys may have some ideas.

Comment: If it's indeed the trajectory or some other feature that requires "memory" over iterations, I don't see a way to transform a single value in absence of others. For example, you could track a country's GDP over time as a measure of the economy's growth, even though different countries will have very different GDPs to begin with. Measuring any GDP at a single point in time will not give you any information about whether the GDP is growing or shrinking, however.

Comment: there is no "memory" required. To be a bit more domain specific: 
- the trajectory depicts euclidean distances over a solver's iterative improvement process; i.e. in i = 1 the distance is 1000000 and in i = 100 it has found a better tour of length 500000. Now, it may be the case that the same type of instance generator has produced an instance where value are much less like 100 and 5 for the distances in i = 1 and 100 resp. So my problem is that my features do rely on the "y" itself but I cannot predict/anticipate which ranges it will take.

Comment: what do you think about normalizing the y values like this:
- shrinking the "y range" through subtracting the min(y) from each y_i
- taking the natural logarithm for each of these values 

by this I would have tried to reduce the y-value spread and at least decouple it from the overal niveau (e.g. y = 1000 in i = 1 minus min(y) = 700 => ln(300) = 5.7 VS y = 10 in i = 1 minus min(y) = 3 => ln(7) = 1.94)